# Json count query, how to pass only the counted value?

Tags: json, django, django-models

So basically, my issue is this json for the queried data2 passes the count number with the counted car brand, is there anyway i could only pass the counted part?

Here is my view, with the queries

```
class DadosDeGrafico1(APIView):
authentication_classes = []
permission_classes = []
def get(self, request, format=None):
    data1 = DataDB.objects.values_list('marca').distinct()
    data2 = DataDB.objects.values_list('marca').annotate(marcas=Count('marca'))
    contexto = {
    'data1':data1,
    'data2':data2
    }
    return Response(contexto)
```

[image]

Basically the result of the query should be only 2 and 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `values` or `values_list` to get just the values you want

```
data2 = DataDB.objects.values('marca').annotate(marcas=Count('marca')).values_list('marcas')
```

A caution though, with this data structure you won't know which 'marca' each number goes with. The first and second queries are not guaranteed to return data in the same order. As you can see they are not in your example output.

Comment: Yeah. i took that in consideration, the front end guy cried a bit so here we are. Thanks for the help nonetheless